# Module compiled with Swift 4.0 cannot be imported in Swift 3.2.1

Tags: swift4, swift3.2, xcode9.1-beta

Swift 4.0 modules were fine in Swift 3.2 apps with Xcode 9.0.

But now, with Xcode 9.1, I get:

> Module compiled with Swift 4.0 cannot be imported in Swift 3.2.1

Or:

> Module compiled with Swift 4.0 cannot be imported in Swift 4.0.1

Comment: I had this error message, too, and it turned out to be caused various syntax errors in my code.  Once I fixed the syntax errors, the error went away.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Swift 4.0 is compatible with Swift 3.2 only.
Swift 4.0.1 is compatible with Swift 3.2.1 only.

So:

- you can't mix 4.0 and 3.2.1
- you can't mix 4.0.1 and 3.2
- you can't mix 4.0 and 4.0.1
- you can't mix 3.2.1 and 3.2

To formulate it differently:

- you can mix Xcode 9.0 supported Swift versions together
- you can mix Xcode 9.1 supported Swift versions together
- you can't mix Xcode 9.0 and Xcode 9.1 Swift versions

If the module was built by you, simply rebuild it with the same Xcode.
If the module was built by a third party, request an Xcode 9.1 compatible build.

Answer (score 7):

It's possible to build using Swift 3.2 in Xcode 9.1 beta 2 by installing the [Xcode 9.0 toolchain](https://swift.org/download/#releases) and using that to build your project.

[image: Swift Toolchain Image]

Then choose the Swift 4.0 release under the Xcode -> Toolchains menu.

You should now be able to build with either Swift 3.2 or 4.0 in Xcode 9.1 b2.

Comment: Oh, correct... but then at the time of stable Xcode 9.1, custom toolchain won't be accepted by iTunes Connect for release.

Comment: That's true. I suppose you could always continue to submit using Xcode 9.0 while testing on Xcode 9.1 beta. Sort of annoying that some of the iPhone X functionality is not working in the current Xcode though.

Answer (score 0):

Using the last Xcode version solved this issue